# ORA-12560: TNS: Error protocol Adapter

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I would like to export database schema with expdp/impdp. For that reason I am trying to do the same steps like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxuL3KVmx1g)  tutorial.

when I enter sqlplus / as sysdba in the command line, I will be ased to enter user name and pasword. When I do this and click Enter, the following errors is comming:

ORA-12560: TNS: Error protocol Adapter

I am using windows 7 and have installed oracle 12c. All oracle services are started. I login from cmd.exe as adminstrator

Comment: open de `cmd` and do this `lsnrctl status` and tell me what's the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know the problem. You said that you did the same steps in the tutorial.

In the tutorial, he did this step `C:>set oracle_sid=db`.

Did you have the same name of the `Oracle SID` ? If you did a default installation, by the default the `Oracle SID` is `orcl` .

In your case, do this `C:>set oracle_sid=ORCL`. To verify the `Oracle SID`, go to this path `C:\oracle\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN` and open the `listener.ora` and check the `host` name.

```
LISTENER =
     (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
         (DESCRIPTION =
             (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
             (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =ORCL)(PORT = 1521)
         )
     )
)
```

If you have `HOST=ORCL`, then you must do this `C:>set oracle_sid=ORCL`. If you have another name, do this `C:>set oracle_sid=NAME_OF_YOUR_HOST`

Comment: This was exactly the problem, thank you so much for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

TNS adpater is because you are creating a local uses under orcl, please create a user under pdborcl, this will solve your connectivity problem.